# indexOf() not working anymore

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with this code :

```
function tabsUpdated(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status != "complete") return;

    console.log(tab.url);
        //displays 'http://www.entraineurdefootonline.fr/League/Transferlist/'

    console.log(tab.url.indexOf('League/TransferList')); //displays -1

    if (tab.url.indexOf('League/TransferList') > -1){
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id)
        loadScripts(tabId);
    }
}
```

As you can see `tab.url.indexOf('League/TransferList')` returns `-1` where it should return `36`. It's very weird, it worked well for weeks and today whitout doing any changes it does this. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZed6/1/) that proves the issue is not from the code. I tried deleting and reloading the extension (with load unpacked extension).

Maybe someone already faced this kind of weirdness ?

Comment: `'TransferList'` vs `'Transferlist'`: `indexOf` is case-sensitive.

Comment: "Transferlist" simple typo: "TransferList"

Comment: i get 36 from your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a problem with upper and lower case letters. In the URL it says `Transferlist` with a lower case `l`, while you check for `TransferList` with an upper case `L`.

As a solution you could convert all strings to lower case using [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) (or upper case using [`toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase), before comparing them:

```
// ...
if (tab.url.toLowerCase().indexOf('League/TransferList'.toLowerCase()) > -1){
// ...
```

Comment: I feel stupid, I will use toLowerCase() before comparing, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other asnwers, if your string can be upper or lower case then you could use a quick case-insensitive regex if needed:

```
if (/transferlist/i.test(tab.url)) {
  ...
}
```